# inotify_rm_watch always returns EINVAL

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, inotify

I have following two functions:

```
static int MessAttrManager_inotifyUnregister(MessPropertyManager* base, int wd){
  MessAttrManager* self = base->_derived;
  int ret;

  printf("INOTIFY REMOV %d\n",wd);
  if ((ret = inotify_rm_watch(self->inotify.descriptor, wd)) < 0)
    return ret;
  printf("INOTIFY REMOV END %d\n",wd);

  return 0;
}

static int MessAttrManager_inotifyRegister(MessPropertyManager* base, char* dir, long flags){
  MessAttrManager* self = base->_derived;
  int wd, ret;

  printf("INOTIFY ADD START %s\n",dir);
  if ((wd = inotify_add_watch(self->inotify.descriptor, dir, flags)) < 0)
    return wd;
  printf("INOTIFY ADD %d %s\n",wd,dir);

  return 0;
}
```

They're the only pieces of code that use `inotify_rm/add_watch` In logs I can clearly see that watch is created successfully by `MessAttrManager_inotifyRegister`. Also events are properly detected. I also see that exactly the same watch descriptor is being removed by `MessAttrManager_inotifyUnregister`. However second function almost always returns `EINVAL`. I have nested hierarchy of watched directories (recursive) and `inotify_rm_watch` only executes successfully on last directory (root) when I'm recursively removing all watches.

Is it standard behavior for nested watches?

Answer (score 1):

`inotify` removes watches from deleted directories on its own and throws `EINVAL` if one tries to explicitly remove watch from deleted directory. In conjunction with fact that inotify event does not contain `wd` of removed child and that `IN_IGNORED` flag is contained in `IN_DELETE` event of parent directory rather than `IN_DELETE_SELF` of actual directory it's insanely inconvenient.